# Invalid Response when communicating with my OBD2 Scanner in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, debugging, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter blue plus library to connect to my obd2 scanner and get a response. I have made my connection, i am able to send commands to scanner successfully. But in response, i do not get a valid response or i get an empty response or i get the same command i sent as a response. HELP PLEASE

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW10H.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds2T3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB3a5.png)
```

I was sending let's say `0105` as command to get vehicle coolant temperature. It should return in response a hex value for temperature but it either returns nothing or `AAAAAAA or 8888888 or same command 0105`

Comment: Does the documentation of your OBD2 scanner state something about that? Have you tested your setup using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?